# Regex PHP match character only if not preceded or followed by same character.

Tags: php, regex

so I am trying to match a back tick **`** but only when it is not more than one in a row:

````
`test` // matches
``test`` // does NOT match

// does NOT match
```java
    test
```
````

BUT it needs to also match if is at the beginning of the string or end, so all three must match.

> `matches`
>
> Text `matches`
>
> Text `matches`EOL

Comment: *I am trying to match a back tick* - please share what you tried.

Comment: lookaround assertions to the rescue (?)

Comment: Hmm, this is good, so I can use it likes `(?=`)`(?!`)[^`]*(?=`)`(?!`)` right? It works fine http://regexr.com/3cad6 Thanks

Comment: `/(?:[^\`]|^)(?!\`\`)(\`)/`

Comment: You need not  backticks themselves, but the text inside?

Comment: Yes, but if I have all its fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**

The regex below matches exactly as the previous one, but consumes the backtick `` ` `` avoiding that an ending backtick is considered a starting backtick when the regex engine searchs for the next one.

```
(?<!`)`([^`\n\r]+)`(?!`)
```

The correct behaviour (extract only the text wrapped inside single backticks) is keeped using a capturing group `` `([^`\n\r]+)` ``.

Use it with `preg_match_all`, try this [online php demo](http://ideone.com/tHOSN8).

Legenda:

- `` (?<!`)` `` a backtick not preceded another one
- `` `([^`\n\r]+)` `` a capturing group that matches everything that is not a backtick or a newline (CR or LF)
- `` `(?!`) `` a backtick not followed by another one

[Updated Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT8mZ1/6)

Comment: This does not work, as it matches the entire line, but should just match the ticks and the stuff inside, but Elias Van Ootegem solution seems to work.

Comment: I've matched the entire line on purpose (i misunderstood), glad something provides you a working solution

Comment: @LukasOppermann: the regex above do exactly what you need (extracting the content inside single backtick), let me know if it works for you. The regex in the comments above is less refined (takes also backticks) and has some redundant controls and flags.

Comment: Hey, it works fine, but this leads to a problem.

When you have code like \`matches\` sdsdfsdf \`sdfasdf\` all three words are matched. So I actually need to match the content including the backticks so this does not happen. So if I change yours to `(?<=(?<!\`))\`[^\`\n\r]+\`(?=(?!\`)) it should be fine.

Comment: @LukasOppermann: i've updated the answer with a new regex to avoid this unwanted behaviour. The functionality is the same (at the really tiny cost of one capturing group). You can find an online php demo [here](http://ideone.com/tHOSN8)